# Insert not saving up

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

My insert is not saving up i dont know i think i mess my coding any help?

Im still trying to figure it up any help would appreciate

```
    if(txt_stock_qty.getText().equals("") || txt_stock_product.getText().equals("") || txt_stock_price.getText().equals("") || txt_stock_total.getText().equals("")){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fill up all data");
                       }else{
             try{



                    String sql1 = "SELECT Product from stocktbl" ;

         pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
         rs=pst.executeQuery();
                 if(rs.next()){
                  String Prob=rs.getString("Product");
                 if(Prob.equals(txt_stock_product.getText())){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existing Data Found");
                 }

                 }else{
                  String sql="INSERT INTO stocktbl (Product,Stock,Price,Total) values(?,?,?,?)";
    pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txt_stock_product.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txt_stock_qty.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txt_stock_price.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txt_stock_total.getText());


    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");

     }
                 }    
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
                       }

        txt_stock_barcode.setText("");
        txt_stock_product.setText("");
        txt_stock_qty.setText("");
        txt_stock_price.setText("");
        txt_stock_total.setText("");
        lbl_stock_barpic.setText("");
        UpdateJTable();

    }
```

after clicking Insert it goes to clear all txt i think i mess it up

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake lies here:

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
pst.execute();
```

You are executing the same preparedstatement twice. Also, when using `INSERT` you should use `pst.executeUpdate();` and can't use `pst.executeQuery();`, because `INSERT` doesn't give a result set. `pst.executeUpdate();` is only used for `SELECT`.

It might be helpful to look at the basics again.

Comment: you mean pst.executeQuery(); is for SELECT AND pst.executeUpdate(); is for insert ?

Comment: executeQuery() is for SELECT; because SELECT yields a resultset. executeUpdate() is for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE and they don't yield a resultset.
You can also just use execute(), which can be used for any SQL statement.

You really should read the basics. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is the site about PreparedStatement. You can find information about other things on the same website.

Comment: Problem solve i just reconfigure the if else and change few Select statement thanks for helping

Comment: Glad, that you found a solution, which fits your plans.